# Dart: Let an exception thrown inside a stream propagate and catch it in the caller

Tags: dart

I would like to have an exception thrown inside stream to be caught and handled outside by the caller.

If I try with a standard try-catch block, like below, it does work: I get **Uncaught Error: Exception**.

By running the snippet code below in DartPad

```dart
void main() async {
  await for (var i in mainStream()) {
    print(i);
  }
}

Stream<int> subStreamA() async* {
  for (var i in List.generate(10, (i) => i)) {
    if (i == 2) {
      throw Exception();
    }
    yield i;
  }
}
Stream<int> subStreamB() async* {
  for (var i in List.generate(10, (i) => i + 10)) {
    yield i;
  }
}

Stream<int> mainStream() async* {
  try {
    yield* subStreamA();
    yield* subStreamB();
  } catch (e) {
    print('CAUGHT! :)');
    yield -1;
  }
}
```

The result is:

```
0
1
Uncaught Error: Exception
```

I would like the exception to be caught, resulting in:

```
0
1
CAUGHT! :)
-1
```

I had some "solution" in mind, but they're kind of horrible :( such as...

```dart
Stream<int> mainStream() async* {
  try {
    Exception? err;
    yield* subStreamA().handleError((e) {
      err = e;
    });
    if (err != null) throw err!;
    yield* subStreamB().handleError((e) {
      err = e;
    });
    if (err != null) throw err!;
  } catch (e) {
    print('CAUGHT! :)');
    yield -1;
  }
}
```

Is there a clean solution leveraging a normal try-catch without dirty tricks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior of `yield*` for `async*` marked method is part of the Dart Language Design which describes this with:

> The `o` stream is listened to, creating a subscription `s`, and for each event
> `x`, or error `e` with stack trace `t`, of `s`:
>
> ...
>
> - Otherwise, `x`, or `e` with `t`, are added to the stream associated with `m`
>   in the order they appear in `o`.

https://dart.dev/guides/language/specifications/DartLangSpec-v2.10.pdf

So in easier terms, this means when we use `yield*` we are forwarding both events and errors (with stacktrace) from the `Stream` we are forwarding.

If you want to catch the exceptions, I think the easiest solution is to rewrite the use of `yield*` to `await for` loops like this:

```
Stream<int> mainStream() async* {
  try {
    await for (final event in subStreamA()) {
      yield event;
    }
    await for (final event in subStreamB()) {
      yield event;
    }
  } catch (e) {
    print('CAUGHT! :)');
    yield -1;
  }
}
```

With this change I get the following output:

```
0
1
CAUGHT! :)
-1
```

Comment: Thanks! It's way cleaner than all solutions I had in mind

Comment: @gianmarcocalbi Updated the answer. The behavior is part of the Dart language specification.

Comment: @gianmarcocalbi If you don't have any further questions and you find my answer satisfying, please accept the answer. :)